# Wordpress Sub-Menu suddenly stopped appearing

Tags: wordpress, submenu

I know this question has been asked similar ways before, but I am not finding a solution. I am trying to get the submenu dropdown to appear when one hovers over the main navigation.

It is a standard wordpress nav menu that worked fine until a few days ago. .

The site is http://www.cktax.com/.

```
header nav .sub-menu a:hover{
color: #555;
}

header .sub-menu li:hover {
background:#eee;
border-radius:4px;
box-shadow:inset 0 0 2px #CCC;
}

nav > ul ul {
display:none;
}

.submenu {
overflow:hidden;
font-size:13px;
height:14px;
}

.submenu ul {
padding-bottom:1px;
}

.submenu strong {
float:left;
}

.submenu li {
float:left;
line-height:1em;
margin:0 16px;
}

header .sub-menu {
position:absolute;
background-color:#FFF;
z-index:2;
left:-12px;
top:40px;
width:220px;
box-shadow:0 0 3px #c3c3c3;
border-radius:8px;
padding:20px;
}

header .sub-menu a {
font-size:14px;
letter-spacing: .5pt;
display:inline-block;
width:100%;
padding:9px 10px;
}

header .sub-menu .sub-menu {
left:231px;
top:0;
}

header .sub-menu .sub-menu:before {
content:'';
}

header .sub-menu li {
position:relative;
margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code in the question in addition to providing a link to it.

Comment: I could have something to do with the javascript errors I see in my console. Start there.

Comment: Reworded question and added the css.

Comment: How do I ID the java errors?

Comment: @user3798170 Your question will probably be reopened soon (just needs 1 more vote currently), however to get someone to answer you I suggest you post only relevant code and if possible a minimal example (e.g. on jsfiddle.net). Not many people are willing to just sort through 50-60 lines of CSS plus whatever your HTML is (which you didn't post).